# Insert into SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert text messages from an inbox to a SQLite Database, but due to some special characters/symbols it doesn't insert properly.

I went through some question in Stackoverflow but nothing seems useful.

I got this code, but it is not working.

```
data.execSQL("INSERT INTO recor(text) VALUES('"+DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(messag)+"')");
```

My database has only one field in it and am trying to insert details of messages along with it. I am putting the details (type, time, number, message) to a single string `message` and `recor` is my table name.

This is what I get as toast when I use a try catch loop.

Error is near:

> "FROM":syntax error:INSERT INTO recor(text) VALUES("FROM 15555215556 Message:-MSG")

Comment: maybe it is just a typo and you mean `record` instead of `recor` ?

Comment: no 'recor' is my table name...

Comment: then maybe `recor.text` instead of `recor(text)`

Comment: is 'messag' also the correct variable?

Comment: @Jimpanzee: that would have been my next question :)

Comment: r u sure about that..? coz every where it was suppose to be tablename(fieldname) not tablename.fieldname

Comment: it is `database_name.table_name(field_name)`

Comment: @Jimpanzee yes am very sure about it...

Comment: Also, don't mix SQL code and data... use parameter binding, because otherwise contents from the data "leak" into your SQL (hello, SQL Injection!), in this case causing the syntax error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the DatabaseAdapter's insert method instead. e.g.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, value);
dbAdapter.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

it looks like your column name is 'text'? this must be wrong, as text is a keyword in sqlite.

Comment: i can't imagine that `text` can't be a column name in sqlite

Comment: yup me too @padde... i dont think text does much problem here... problem is when some symbols come it doesn't get inserted..

Answer (score 0):

Your final SQL string seems to include two sets of quotes around the string you are inserting, so I assume the `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString` method adds its own quotes around the string.

Therefore, your code should be:

`data.execSQL("INSERT INTO recor(text) VALUES("+DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(messag)+")");`